# Search in ignited datatable for add_column that callback from helpers

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatables

i use ignited-datatable library

this is my add column code:

```
$this->load->helper('promo');
$this->datatables->add_column('status', '$1', 'render_status_promo(tanggal_mulai,tanggal_berakhir)');
```

and this is my helper function:

```
if ( ! function_exists('render_status_promo'))
{
  function render_status_promo($tanggal_mulai = '',$tanggal_berakhir = '')
  {
    $tanggal = dateonly();  
    if($tanggal_mulai > $tanggal){
        return 'Menunggu';
    }elseif($tanggal_mulai <= $tanggal && $tanggal_berakhir >= $tanggal){
        return 'Sedang Berjalan';
    }else{
        return 'Kadaluwarsa';
    }
  }
}
```

That's totally works, but the problem is on the search. it cannot search for that column.

Any of you know something to fix this?